# Why is SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler more than the number of batches?

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

I am working on batch apex and I have just tried writing a simple code for learning purpose. In the start method I am querying the records limiting them to 7, and I am running the batch job from the anonymous window by setting the batch size to 1 in order to get the better understanding of how execute method is being called in chunks. According to my understanding, the execute method must have been called 7 times for 7 records when the batch size is set to 1. After executing the batch when I see the logs tab in developer console, I see something like `SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler` in the operations column. When I researched about the same, I came to know that for each chunk that the batch job processes, `SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler` will be there. So going by that logic, my logs should have 7 instances of this operation, but actually there are 8. If I have 8 records, there are 9 instances of this log operation. What is that extra log instance pointing to? Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you opened each one of them and analysed it?

Comment: I suspect this is related to the fact there are three aspects to the batch: start, which defines the data that is to be processed by the batch; execute which accepts "chunks" of the over-all data, one chunk at a time; finish which is called when all "chunks" have been processed. Each of these invocations occurs as a separate async execution. I am suspecting the last chunk handler in your list is generated to handle additional data, but when it determines there is none it actually performs the "finish" execution. (Only an educated guess)